# Keyboard Media/Volume keys not working, only on this computer, and only this keyboard

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, keyboard

The media keys, volume knob, sleep button and mute button on my "Das Keyboard 4 Professional" keyboard stopped working a few weeks ago after a reboot that I think was caused by a Windows Update.

I've tried the following steps to try and solve the issue:

- Try a different keyboard - The media keys on a logitech wireless usb keyboard work fine, even in the same USB port.
- Try keyboard with another PC - When plugged in to my laptop the Das Keyboard media/volume keys work fine.
- Try another USB port - No difference
- Tried completely wiping any trace of the keyboard from the registry/device manager, then plugging it in again - No difference.
- Created a new user on the PC - No difference.
- Ensured the HID Human Interface Service is running.
- Disable touch keyboard and related services.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Welcome to the Microsoft Windows Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to an unrelated issue I ended up reinstalling the Razer Synapse drivers for my mouse, and afterwards the media keys + volume knob started working again on my Das Keyboard.

Comment: Similar issue for me with my Das Keyboard Pro.

I previously had a Razer keyboard and still have a Razer mouse. Opening Device Manager and uninstalling the Keyboard/Mouse devices (including drivers) then rebooting fixed things up for me.

Answer (score 0):

According to the first two tests, both of your keyboard and computer are ok. According to your test 4, driver should also be fine.

I guess that there are some software has conflict with your keyboard’s Media/Volume/sleep keys, execute a clean boot to check again or use your keyboard in safe mode.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've just tried safe mode, the various media/volume keys still don't work, both on my normal account and the new user account I created earlier for testing. I assume by "clean boot" you just meant a restart, that also had no effect.